# My old clarinet smells musty. How to freshen it up?

Tags: maintenance, clarinet

I have an old bass clarinet I haven't played for years. I opened it up and it smells really musty. The reeds were icky so I threw them out. How do I get the smell out without damaging it? It's not mouldy, just smells of cellar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how bad it is. I would first try setting it out in a safe place, not in the sun. Give it a few days. If it is really bad take it to a trusted repair shop. I never take mine apart and I never put anything but a cleaning swab inside.

Comment: I will try this first. I will put it somewhere with a good flow of air and report back in a week.

Comment: If it has been years since played then you may want to have the pads replaced as well as the cords.

Comment: This worked very well. I put the case out on the balcony and the clarinet on its stand by an open window and left it for a week. Almost good as new!

Comment: I just had the one problem with this; the corks dried out completely and I had to re-grease them. next time I'll grease them first ...

Answer (score 3):

I find that the mustiness smell mostly comes from the case. I'd suggest vacuuming the case then leaving it out in the sun for a few hours.

For the instrument, wipe it down with a dry rag or paper towel. You can get any of the dust out from between the keys using a small soft paint brush or q-tip.

If the smell still does not go away and it seems that it is the instrument itself that is the problem, the clarinet is in need of a repadding and should be taken to a repair shop.

Comment: This is a good tip. I will try this and report back.